# locate Excel add-ins Library path

Tags: excel, installation, add-in

I've got an Excel add-in which i'm trying to get to install itself into the Excel Add-ins path.

The add-in can be installed in one of two places, within the users profile, or within the MS office install.

The later is preferable, as i don't want to have to worry system admins about new users login & cannot see my add-in.

Then there is the issue of locating the office install path, there are registry keys you can look it up, but you need to look up the excel guid, which can have a dozen + permutations, from version, architecture, msi to click-to-run, etc, etc (all of which i cannot find). Or else a predefined list of known office install paths, again a dozen permutations.

And then there is the architecture issue, a 32-bit add-in wont run on 64-bit office and vice versa.

And then there is the issue were office 32-bit can be installed in the 64-bit program files, thanks Microsoft!

So I've come up with the following batch script. I'm concerned there are other office install paths i'm not aware off...?

I'm trying to be compatible with Office 2007 - 2016.

Anything I've overlooked would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

James

```
@ECHO off

SET FROM=%1
SET FROM=%FROM:"=%

ECHO "installed in %FROM%"

SET INSTALLED=0

SET XLL_FILEx64=ChiefExcelInterfaceAddIn64-packed.xll
SET XLL_FILE=ChiefExcelInterfaceAddIn-packed.xll
SET PFx86=%ProgramFiles(x86)%

echo "PFx86=%PFx86%"

REM "32-bit OS"
IF "%PFx86%" == "" (
    SET PFx86=%ProgramFiles%
)


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%x in ( 
"Microsoft Office\Office16"
"Microsoft Office\root\Office16"
"Microsoft Office 16\root\office16"
"Microsoft Office\Office15"
"Microsoft Office\root\office15"
"Microsoft Office 15\root\office15"
"Microsoft Office\Office14"
"Microsoft Office\root\office14"
"Microsoft Office 14\root\office14"
"Microsoft Office\Office12"
"Microsoft Office\root\office12"
"Microsoft Office 12\root\office12"
"Microsoft Office 16\ClientX86\Root\Office16"
"Microsoft Office 16\ClientX64\Root\Office16"
"Microsoft Office 15\ClientX86\Root\Office15"
"Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\Root\Office15"
"Microsoft Office 14\ClientX86\Root\Office14"
"Microsoft Office 14\ClientX64\Root\Office14"
) do (
    REM echo %%x



    for %%y in (
"%ProgramW6432%"
"%PFx86%"
    ) do (
        SET "foo=%%y\%%x"
        SET foo=!foo:"=!

        REM echo !foo!

        IF EXIST "!foo!\Library" (
            ECHO "found it !foo!\Library"

            REM 64-bit excel.exe
            file\bin\file "!foo!\excel.exe" | find "PE32+"
            echo !errorlevel!

            IF !errorlevel! == 0 (
                ECHO COPY /Y "%FROM%\%XLL_FILEx64%" "!foo!\Library" 64-bit
                COPY /Y "%FROM%\%XLL_FILEx64%" "!foo!\Library"
                SET INSTALLED=1

            ) else (
                REM 32-bit excel.exe
                file\bin\file "!foo!\excel.exe" | find "PE32"
                echo !errorlevel!
                IF !errorlevel! == 0 (
                    ECHO COPY /Y "%FROM%\%XLL_FILE%" "!foo!\Library" 32-bit
                    COPY /Y "%FROM%\%XLL_FILE%" "!foo!\Library"
                    SET INSTALLED=1
                )
            )

        )
    )
)




echo %INSTALLED%
pause
```